# Google My map control

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

Is there Google My Map control available for free download, which use to draw shapes on the map

Answer (score 1):

For the API V2 there's GeometryControls:

http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/

For V3 I'm not aware of any.

Marcelo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I'm Keep getting this error 
"11:45:31:453GeometryControls#getInfoWindowHtml says: failed to get html from template"
whats this error about?

Comment: Since the library is very much detailed its hard to figure out the content.Can't i simply download this whole library and use it in my own project